# How to use this tutorial on time series forecasting (for beginners)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am following TensorFlow’s [tutorial on time series forecasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#dense). I created and saved the model like in this tutorial. There are many examples in the manual for learning, but few uses of it.

How can I use the saved model in another script? How can I predict temperature, e.g., “01.01.2017 00:10:00”? How can I get the temperature value in a normal format?

Example code from the tutorial:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop
import os
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

zip_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip',
    fname='jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip',
    extract=True)
csv_path, _ = os.path.splitext(zip_path)

df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
# Slice [start:stop:step], starting from index 5 take every 6th record.

df = df[5::6]
date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date Time'), format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')

wv = df['wv (m/s)']
bad_wv = wv == -9999.0
wv[bad_wv] = 0.0

max_wv = df['max. wv (m/s)']
bad_max_wv = max_wv == -9999.0
max_wv[bad_max_wv] = 0.0

# The above inplace edits are reflected in the DataFrame.
df['wv (m/s)'].min()

wv = df.pop('wv (m/s)')
max_wv = df.pop('max. wv (m/s)')

# Convert to radians.
wd_rad = df.pop('wd (deg)')*np.pi / 180

# Calculate the wind x and y components.
df['Wx'] = wv*np.cos(wd_rad)
df['Wy'] = wv*np.sin(wd_rad)

# Calculate the max wind x and y components.
df['max Wx'] = max_wv*np.cos(wd_rad)
df['max Wy'] = max_wv*np.sin(wd_rad)

timestamp_s = date_time.map(pd.Timestamp.timestamp)

day = 24*60*60
year = (365.2425)*day

df['Day sin'] = np.sin(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / day))
df['Day cos'] = np.cos(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / day))
df['Year sin'] = np.sin(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / year))
df['Year cos'] = np.cos(timestamp_s * (2 * np.pi / year))

fft = tf.signal.rfft(df['T (degC)'])
f_per_dataset = np.arange(0, len(fft))

n_samples_h = len(df['T (degC)'])
hours_per_year = 24*365.2524
years_per_dataset = n_samples_h/(hours_per_year)

# f_per_year = f_per_dataset/years_per_dataset
# plt.step(f_per_year, np.abs(fft))
# plt.xscale('log')
# plt.ylim(0, 400000)
# plt.xlim([0.1, max(plt.xlim())])
# plt.xticks([1, 365.2524], labels=['1/Year', '1/day'])
# _ = plt.xlabel('Frequency (log scale)')

column_indices = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(df.columns)}

n = len(df)
train_df = df[0:int(n*0.7)]
val_df = df[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)]
test_df = df[int(n*0.9):]

num_features = df.shape[1]

train_mean = train_df.mean()
train_std = train_df.std()

train_df = (train_df - train_mean) / train_std
val_df = (val_df - train_mean) / train_std
test_df = (test_df - train_mean) / train_std

df_std = (df - train_mean) / train_std
# df_std = df_std.melt(var_name='Column', value_name='Normalized')
# plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
# ax = sns.violinplot(x='Column', y='Normalized', data=df_std)
# _ = ax.set_xticklabels(df.keys(), rotation=90)

# //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class WindowGenerator():
def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift,
            train_df=train_df, val_df=val_df, test_df=test_df,
            label_columns=None):
    # Store the raw data.
    self.train_df = train_df
    self.val_df = val_df
    self.test_df = test_df

    # Work out the label column indices.
    self.label_columns = label_columns
    if label_columns is not None:
    self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                                    enumerate(label_columns)}
    self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                        enumerate(train_df.columns)}

    # Work out the window parameters.
    self.input_width = input_width
    self.label_width = label_width
    self.shift = shift

    self.total_window_size = input_width + shift

    self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
    self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]

    self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
    self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
    self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]

def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join([
        f'Total window size: {self.total_window_size}',
        f'Input indices: {self.input_indices}',
        f'Label indices: {self.label_indices}',
        f'Label column name(s): {self.label_columns}'])
# //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
def split_window(self, features):
inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
if self.label_columns is not None:
    labels = tf.stack(
        [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],
        axis=-1)

# Slicing doesn't preserve static shape information, so set the shapes
# manually. This way the `tf.data.Datasets` are easier to inspect.
inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

return inputs, labels

WindowGenerator.split_window = split_window

def plot(self, model=None, plot_col='T (degC)', max_subplots=3, num=None):
inputs, labels = self.example
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8), num=num)
plot_col_index = self.column_indices[plot_col]
max_n = min(max_subplots, len(inputs))
for n in range(max_n):
    plt.subplot(max_n, 1, n+1)
    plt.ylabel(f'{plot_col} [normed]')
    plt.plot(self.input_indices, inputs[n, :, plot_col_index],
            label='Inputs', marker='.', zorder=-10)

    if self.label_columns:
    label_col_index = self.label_columns_indices.get(plot_col, None)
    else:
    label_col_index = plot_col_index

    if label_col_index is None:
    continue

    plt.scatter(self.label_indices, labels[n, :, label_col_index],
                edgecolors='k', label='Labels', c='#2ca02c', s=64)
    if model is not None:
    predictions = model(inputs)
    plt.scatter(self.label_indices, predictions[n, :, label_col_index],
                marker='X', edgecolors='k', label='Predictions',
                c='#ff7f0e', s=64)

    if n == 0:
    plt.legend()

plt.xlabel('Time [h]')

WindowGenerator.plot = plot

def make_dataset(self, data):
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    data=data,
    targets=None,
    sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
    sequence_stride=1,
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=32,)

ds = ds.map(self.split_window)

return ds

WindowGenerator.make_dataset = make_dataset

@property
def train(self):
return self.make_dataset(self.train_df)

@property
def val(self):
return self.make_dataset(self.val_df)

@property
def test(self):
return self.make_dataset(self.test_df)

@property
def example(self):
"""Get and cache an example batch of `inputs, labels` for plotting."""
result = getattr(self, '_example', None)
if result is None:
    # No example batch was found, so get one from the `.train` dataset
    result = next(iter(self.train))
    # And cache it for next time
    self._example = result
return result

WindowGenerator.train = train
WindowGenerator.val = val
WindowGenerator.test = test
WindowGenerator.example = example

single_step_window = WindowGenerator(
    input_width=1, label_width=1, shift=1,
    label_columns=['T (degC)'])

MAX_EPOCHS = 20

def compile_and_fit(model, window, patience=2, save=False):
    early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                    patience=patience,
                                                    mode='min')

    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

    history = model.fit(window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                    validation_data=window.val,
                    callbacks=[early_stopping])
    if save == True:
        model.save('./saved_model')

    return history

dense = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1),
])

history = compile_and_fit(dense, single_step_window, save=True)

val_performance = {}
performance = {}

val_performance['Dense'] = dense.evaluate(single_step_window.val)
performance['Dense'] = dense.evaluate(single_step_window.test, verbose=0)
dense.summary()
```

Next I need to load the model and use:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./saved_model')
loaded_model.summary()
```

What's next?

Comment: Preprocess your data `x` like you did for training and then call `predictions = loaded_model(x)`

Comment: please give me complete code example. I don't understand

Comment: The code as posted is not valid: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. Can you [provide](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74487950/edit) the actual code? (But *********************** ***without*** *********************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today)

Comment: Does the current answer have any merit? Or is it completely bogus? (Not rhetorical questions.)

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways you may consider.

1. model.save() and model.load()
2. model.save_weights() and model.load_wights()
3. Export parameters as arrays. We discussed here no need for target API install. You can use any random function from the target machine with the parameter.
4. Transform and copy the working directory
5. etc.

Time conversation. You know that the database has unique time units, Oracle, Informix, and SQL. They can display as unix_time or binary sequences as designed in many applications. The unix_time in the communications response with a clock or response time to convert per security method if any. You need to synchronize the clock and response to the correct binary format or time format for extracting data when request or response information extraction, number as binary, and then string exports.

```
TAI (17 September 2004)       UTC (16 to 17 September 2004)    [Unix time][1]
2004-09-17T00:00:30.75       2004-09-16T23:59:58.75            1095379198.75
```

Sample: Export trained parameters from the model. It is easy to print out at any of the steps, but working coefficients respond to the target environment with significant feedback.

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.95 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        print( model.get_weights()[0].shape )            # (3, 3, 4, 32)
        print( model.get_weights()[1].shape )            # (32,)

custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=10000, callbacks=[custom_callback] )
```

Comment: @JirayuKaewprateep No, the picture does not help to understand anything in your code or answer. Please refrain to include them.

Comment: This is referenced in [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421793/is-the-re-use-of-the-image-on-these-posts-appropriate).